# Accessing image files in Eclipse?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, image, path

My source directory goes like:

```
> Project Name
   > Java Resources
      > src
         > servlets
         > Images
           > image1.jpg (the images I'm trying to access)
           > image2.jpg
   > WebContent
      > META-INF
      > WEB-INF
      > index.html (my homepage)
```

And in my homepage (index.html) is just a basic HTML:

```
<html>
   <head>
      ...
   </head>

   <body>
      ...
      <img src="/Images/image1.jpg" alt="image 1">
      <img src="/Images/image2.jpg" alt="image 2">

      ...
   </body>

</html>
```

But all that's showing when I run my server is the "alt" which is "image 1" and "image 2"

How do I properly access the file paths of my images assuming that I have an "Images" folder in my folder structure inside my "src" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why

> But all that's showing when I run my server is the "alt" which is "image 1" and "image 2"

is because you put the image files in the wrong directory. Here is a screen shot of an example web application directory structure from the Servlet 3.0 specification:

[image]

So you have to move the `Images` directory to `WebContent` and the images should be accessible from a web client.